# How to fetch an Ember.js model from a different URL?

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to build a "my account" page for the current user. Usually I do something like `store.find('user', id)`. The API endpoint which returns the data for the current user is `/account` but I need to load this data into a User model. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to modify the buildURL method of your adapter...

e.g.

```
export default ApplicationAdapter.extend({
    buildURL : function(type, id) {
        // replace the following line with your own code
        var currentUserID = 101; 

        if (id === currentUserID) {
            return this.namespace + "/account";
        } else {
            return this.namespace + "/users/" + id; //assuming this is your api endpoint
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the model namespace from `users` to `account`, you implement the [pathForType](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.16/classes/DS.RESTAdapter/methods/pathForType?anchor=pathForType) hook.

It would be something like this

**app/adapters/user.js**

```
import Adapter from './application';

export default Adapter.extend({
  pathForType() {
    return 'account';
  }
});
```

To additionally support a singleton resource for this query, you can implement the [urlForFindRecord](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.16/classes/DS.RESTAdapter/methods/urlForFindRecord?anchor=urlForFindRecord) hook.  In this case, all you need to do is not give an ID to _buildUrl to make it do what you want.

```
import Adapter from './application';

export default Adapter.extend({
  pathForType() {
    return 'account';
  },
  urlForFindRecord(id, modelName) {
    return this._buildUrl(modelName);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure how this would work though. Is this saying all user models use `account` instead of `users`? I don't want to change the default behavior of the User model.

Comment: are you saying only the current user (user 1) should be `/account` but that you might do `/user/2` still?

Comment: Heh, I noticed that. =] however, my comment still applies...I only want to fetch data from a different endpoint for one specific route. I could create an "Account" model but it would be identical to the user model's properties.

Comment: If so, there are two equally easy ways to attain that, let me know.

Comment: Yeah this is a "singleton" route that returns the same thing as `/users/:id` without having to know the ID of the current user.